# JavaFX (ImageView | CSS-Background-Image) Button bug

Tags: css, user-interface, button, javafx, imageview

I'm having problems with setting the background image of a button in a resizable JavaFX-Scene. The background images seem to fade out when resizing the window over a certain size. The problem appears when using ImageView in a button as well as when setting the background image via CSS.

I've uploaded a video on YouTube for demonstration:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svMemJnaax0

You can see the background images disappearing when resizing the window.
The bug is reproducible under Windows and Linux.

It only seems to happen with some png-icons.

This is how it looks like when resizing the window, the image in the right button moves to the left out of the button area when increasing window size to the right. Only the right button is affected, the left one is not:
http://oi57.tinypic.com/20k3bqg.jpg

Here is the FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="288.0" prefWidth="862.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <BorderPane layoutX="45.0" layoutY="20.0" minHeight="100.0" minWidth="200.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="10.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
         <bottom>
            <HBox alignment="TOP_RIGHT" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <children>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="24.0" prefWidth="50.0" styleClass="googlebutton" stylesheets="@style.css">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets right="5.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </Button>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="24.0" prefWidth="50.0" styleClass="iconbutton" stylesheets="@style.css">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="5.0" />
                     </HBox.margin></Button>
               </children>
               <BorderPane.margin>
                  <Insets top="5.0" />
               </BorderPane.margin>
            </HBox>
         </bottom>
         <center>
            <ListView prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
         </center>
         <top>
            <Label text="List" BorderPane.alignment="TOP_LEFT">
               <BorderPane.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="5.0" />
               </BorderPane.margin>
            </Label>
         </top>
         <HBox.margin>
            <Insets left="20.0" />
         </HBox.margin>
      </BorderPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

And the style.css:

```
.iconbutton {
    -fx-background-image:  url("http://s28.postimg.org/5nsybhb65/round57.png");
    -fx-background-size: 24,24;
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.googlebutton {
    -fx-background-image:  url("https://www.google.de/images/google_favicon_128.png");
    -fx-background-size: 24,24;
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Has anyone else encountered such problem before?

Thanks,
Jan

Comment: Do not link to code in an offsite zip file.  Edit your question to include an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with the code inline.

Comment: Seems to be a scaling issue. After resizing the icon from 512*512 to 32*32 to show it as 24*24, it works.

Comment: Now that I took the time to complete your code and try it out, I'm rather disappointed that this works on Win7 with Java 8u40. What a waste of time ... regarding your problem, you could try other css size options, not just pixel definitions.